# Polymer Dart core-input validation not working if multiline attribute binded to polymer expression

Tags: data-binding, dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

I'm facing a weird issue. I've a core-input element in my custom polymer element. I set it required, so when it is empty the invalid attribute is true. I want it also multiline therefore I set the attribute multiline to true and it works fine.

If I set the attribute multiline through a binding expression to true the validation stops working.

Here the HTML code:

```dart
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../../packages/core_elements/core_input.html">

    <polymer-element name="main-app">
      <template>
        <core-input label="Type something..." required={{required}} multiline?={{multiline}} value={{input}} invalid={{invalid}}></core-input><br>
        invalid: {{invalid}}
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
    </polymer-element>
```

And the Dart code:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String input = '123';
  @observable bool required = true;
  @observable bool multiline = true;
  @observable bool invalid;

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

}
```

Am I binding the multiline attribute in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but as far as I remember it is not supported to switch between single- and multiline after the element was initialized. Beside that it seems this capability is about to be remove entirely.

- https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/commit/e185e5bbc6f623c3869e441843dc156c04405ad0
- https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/issues/44

`core-input` was changed so that it extends `<input>` and if you want to use a multiline you have to use `<textarea>` instead.

This was committed 17 days ago. The docs for Polymer.js don't reflect these changes yet.

Comment: I'm not really switching between the two modes, the variable value is constant. Maybe its value is applied after the input element has been initialized. I will check.